# R subset/create a data frame by For Loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, datatable

I'm doing a For Loop with R in order to get the last non-NA value of each row. and I will HAVE TO USE For Loop. My data looks like:

```
col1      col2      col3      col4
 A        NA         NA        NA
 B         C         NA        NA
 D         E         F         NA
```

What I've tried so far is:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  index <- as.numeric(max(which(!is.na(df[i,]))))
  product <- df[i, .SD, .SDcols = index]
  print(product )
}
```

Then R gives a result as:

```
    col1
  1:A
    col2
  1:C
    col3
  1:F
```

But what I actually want is a table like below:

```
Product ColName
  A      col1
  C      col2
  F      col3
```

I tried `as.data.table(df[i, .SD, .SDcols = index])` and `as.data.frame(df[i, .SD, .SDcols = index])`, but they both don't work. 
Please let me know if there's any way I can 'switch' the result I have. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So do you actually want a data.frame/data.table? Or just something that looks like that when printed? Using a forloop is a terrible idea if you want one object in the end. Why do you "HAVE" to use one? If this is a homework question, then you should ask your instructor for help. They clearly have some non-standard R solution in mind if a loop is required. Such a solution would not help other R users on this site.

Comment: Are all your columns of the same data-type? If so transpose, lapply, filter out the NAs, take the last entry. ... and please! Don't use for loops

Comment: @MrFlick Hi, really thank you for your reply. I want to use a for loop because I have a really large data set. I want to get a table as what I showed in the question, and it will link to some other stuff later.

Comment: @RussHyde Really appreciate for your advice! I was using for loop because that was the only way I think about. Just wondering would you mind to share a more detailed way to solve the problem? Like the lapply part. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the `tidyverse` suite of packges.  (It's not a for-loop, sorry).

```
library(tidyverse)
result <- df %>%
  mutate(row_num = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(ColName, Product, -row_num, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(col_num = str_match(ColName,"\\d+$")) %>%
  group_by(row_num) %>%
  summarize(
    Product = Product[which.max(col_num)],
    ColName = ColName[which.max(col_num)]
  )
```

If you aren't  familiar with the pipe operator (`%>%`), it passes the result of the previous function as the 1st argument in the next function.  It's a way to avoid nesting a ton of parenthesis when you call one function after another.